# How to check if CMTime is valid in Swift?

Tags: swift

In Obj-C I could use the preprocessor macro `CMTIME_IS_VALID` for this.

In Swift, preprocessor macros don't exist, so I can't use this. Any other easy way to do this check? Of course, I could rewrite the definition of the macro below, but isn't there any better way to do this?

```
 #define CMTIME_IS_VALID(time) ((Boolean)(((time).flags & kCMTimeFlags_Valid) != 0))
```

Comment: was looking for this in objective-c so thanks!

Answer (score 15):

You can define a custom extension with a read-only computed property `isValid`:

```
extension CMTime {
    var isValid : Bool { return (flags & .Valid) != nil }
}
```

which is then used as

```
let cm:CMTime = ...
if cm.isValid { ... }
```

**Update:**  As of **Swift 2 / Xcode 7,** `CMTIME_IS_VALID` is imported
into Swift as

```
func CMTIME_IS_VALID(time: CMTime) -> Bool
```

therefore a custom extension is not needed anymore. 
*If* you want to define a `isValid` property then the syntax in
Swift 2 would be

```
extension CMTime {
    var isValid : Bool { return flags.contains(.Valid) }
}
```