# why is this variable considered to not be a number

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, avaudioplayer

I have this code written out and then a println statement set off on a timer however all that is printed to the console is "nan"

```
    var songTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime())
```

I am lost as to why this is considered not a number and how I can convert it to one.

Comment: What is the CMTimeGetSeconds call for?

Comment: @matt so that I can convert it of type CMTime to a float

Comment: But AVAudioPlayer current time is not a CMTime.

Comment: CMTimeGetSeconds returns a Float64, so I'm not exactly sure what the heck you're trying to do.  You might want to show more code to explain better.  Also, make sure `player.currentTime() `is valid.   I have a feeling it's bogus.

Comment: `AVAudioPlayer.currentTime` is `NSTimeInterval` which is basically the seconds you want... I don't know what are you trying to do...

Comment: I think the OP is using AVPlayer, not AVAudioPlayer. AVPlayer's currentTime() method returns a CMTime.

Comment: You can check if a CMTime represents a valid value, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262700/how-to-check-if-cmtime-is-valid-in-swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if it is valid by:

```
if (isnan(songTime)) {
    // doing ...
}
```

One of the cases you get a var = "nan" is doing a divide with denominator = 0. Check `CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime())` carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this code and it worked just fine. I have to conclude that player.currentTime() is not a CMTime.

```
   var songTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(CMTimeMake(64, 125))
    print(songTime)
```

...sometimes xcode gliches and i just delete everything in the file build the project. and then control z the delete undoing it and build the project only to find it suddenly works.